# How do I return a Json object from Action Attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

when overriding OnActionExecuting, how do I return a Json result without passing to action?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   if (/* whatever */)
   {
      var result = new JsonResult();
      result.Data = /* json data */;
      filterContext.Result = result;
      return;
   }

   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
   return;
}
```

Comment: Set the Data property of the result to the Json data that you want to return.

Comment: i've had to add `result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;` for it to work

Comment: Thanks for the `JsonRequestBehavior` tip! Just what I was looking for =)

Answer (score 2):

I find it useful to use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to generate the json output. This has many advantages, for example JSON properties can be hidden under certain conditions.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (/* whatever */)
    {
        var result = new ResultModel(); // your json model
        ContentResult content = new ContentResult();
        content.ContentType = "application/json";
        content.Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        filterContext.Result = content;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```