# where to set default redirection url if session expires?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using session in my cartnig application but i want it should redirect to index page if any momnet any where the session expires.

Where should i code it and what should be right approach.

I am writing it to global.asax

```
{

    Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");

}
```

is it a right approach?

Comment: I've always done a base controller and had all subsequent controllers inherit from that base. In the base I do my session checks in the `OnActionExecuted` override, but I don't see anything wrong with it being in the global.asax

Comment: but i am facing a problem with this approach if somewhere i am using Ajax call and session expires it redirect a partial view index to same page instead of redirecting it. what should be approach in that case at global level.

Comment: for ajax calls you have to handle in OnActionExecuting by checking if Request is Ajax or normal

Comment: Ah I see, you didn't specify that in your question ;) .. In the case of Ajax, that is where having a base controller and then doing your checks in the `OnActionExecuted` could come in handy. You could return a json object from that method indicating that the session has expired. From there you could alter your ajax to alert user to refresh the page or re-login. This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678344/how-do-i-return-a-json-object-from-action-attribute

Comment: what i do whit ajax is check if ajax request as ehsan said, if it is i return a Unauthorized error on the response (401), and on may layout i call a script that catches the 401 error and opens a modal dialog whit a log form

Comment: but on action executing also execute the action i want to terminate the action so that i return from onaction executing only.